# Anchoring a PopupMenu to an ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-menu, android-popupwindow

I have an ImageView that opens a PopupMenu on click. How can I set the PopupMenu to display at a certain position? The PopupMenu will serve as a drop down menu and I would like the top right corner of the PopupMenu to be where the user clicked. See images below for illustration:

What I have currently:

[image]

What I want:

[image]

The relevant code:

```
mNavViewDropDown= navViewHeader.findViewById(R.id.navview_header_expand);
mNavViewDropDown.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(getContext(), mNavViewDropDown);
        //Inflating the Popup using xml file
        popup.getMenuInflater()
                .inflate(R.menu.menu_navview_header_, popup.getMenu());
        //registering popup with OnMenuItemClickListener
        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                Toast.makeText(
                        getContext(),
                        "You Clicked : " + item.getTitle(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show();
                return true;
            }
        });
        popup.show(); //showing popup menu
    }
});
```

Comment: use drop down instead of popupmenu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So instead of using that hacky drop down pop up menu, I realized there is much better tool already made for exactly this:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner#java

Answer (score 0):

You can set the gravity of the popup menu.

`popup.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);`

That being said, what you are doing is more of a hack. There is no guarantee that it will show up in the left. You should either use an expandableListView or make your own expandable view. Try this library : https://github.com/AAkira/ExpandableLayout. It provides an easy way to show an expandable view.